# vim error_log at 95.5% cpu and 55.0% ram!

Tags: vim

My server has been crashing, a quick check of `ps aux` shows:

```
 root     11905 95.5 55.0 1151616 1135256 pts/0 R+   09:05  40:38 vim error_log
```

Surely this can't be right? Am I reading this right? This seems to be very dire!

If this is really using 95% cpu and 55% memory then how can I stop it/fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very large file is being opened with `vim`, a text editor. To stop `vim`, kill it (PID taken from the second column of `ps aux`):

```
kill 11905
```

When checking log files, I suggest you to use `less` instead as you do not need fancy editing features:

```
less error_log
```

Comment: I normally use cat. Ah cool, kill has stopped it. Could that be what's causing the out of memory errors?

Comment: Also, I figured `error_log` was the apache error log which was MAHOOSIVE! So I also deleted that.

Comment: Other useful tools for log analysis are `tail`, `uniq` and `grep`. See their manpages for more information.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you. I'm primarily a programmer, and have a basic understanding of the hardware/server side of stuff, but stuff like this I'm still learning about and stumbling upon when I have issues like this. Thanks for your help and insight. :) Very useful

Answer (score 1):

You need also restart apache, or it continues to log to the deleted file.

Comment: cool :) i did that anyway.